# Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops. I am getting this error Only on calling toggleLoad from usecontext on Get Api's in useEffect.

I tried to fix it using toggleLoad instead of toggleLoad(). It didn't Worked Page loaded but without Loader. Even after Using callback function also it didn't fix.

```
const fetchData = () => { 
setLoad(true); 
toggleLoad(); 
const payload = {}; 
axios.post('', payload) 
.then(res => { 
let data = res.data.response; 
if (data && data.length === 0) 
{ setNodata(true); } 
else { 
setNodata(false); 
} 
setDData(data); 
setLoad(false); toggleLoad(); 
console.log(res.data); 
}) 
}
```

Comment: This is a fairly basic, common error. We can't help you much without seeing the offending code and its relevant context.

Comment: [edit] your post please, don't put important info in comments